How to build a ImmutableListMultimap with sorted values
I am trying to build an ImmutableListMultimap which has sorted values. I tried the following but toImmutableListMultimap supports only value mapper and not the list of value mapper. Is there any other alternative to this?
Ordering<StatsByDimensions> valueOrdering =
        Ordering.natural().onResultOf(StatsByDimensions::getCost);
ImmutableListMultimap<Dimension, StatsByDimensions> statsByDimenisonMap =
        Multimaps.index(listOfStats, StatsByDimensions::getDimension)
            .asMap()
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(
                toImmutableListMultimap(
                    entry -> entry.getKey(),
                    entry -> valueOrdering.immutableSortedCopy(entry.getValue())));

error:
incompatible types: inference variable V has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: path.to.StatsByDimensions
    lower bounds: com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList<E>javac


Sure.  You don't need to use streams.
ImmutableListMultimap.Builder<Dimension, StatsByDimensions> statsByDimensionMapBuilder =
    ImmutableListMultimap.builder();
statsByDimensionMapBuilder.orderValuesBy(
    Comparator.comparing(StatsByDimensions::getCost));
for (StatsByDimensions statsByDimensions : listOfStats) {
  statsByDimensionMapBuilder.put(
    StatsByDimensions.getDimension(statsByDimensions), statsByDimensions);
}
return statsByDimensionMapBuilder.build();

